# How do I catch the HTML generated by a function?

Tags: php, html

I have a php function that generates HTML code like below

```
function j_uf_SomeFunction($some_var) {
    ?><div class="db_photo">
        <img alt="<?php echo some_php_function ?>" src="<?php echo $some_var; ?>" />
    </div><?php
}
```

Of course, its much more advanced and add all sorts of user options.

In most case I place this function inline, as opposed to have to append it to a string. However, I've come to the first occurrence (probably not the last occurrence) where I need to store the rendered HTML in a string and not have it sent straight off to the parser for building the page.

I need to cut the function off and tell it to take the html generated and store it in a string, and not send it off to the page, only on certain situations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function j_uf_SomeFunction($some_var) {
    ob_start();
    ?><div class="db_photo">
        <img alt="<?php echo some_php_function ?>" src="<?php echo $some_var; ?>" />
    </div><?php
  return ob_get_clean();//suggestion by GWW
}
```

ob_start() is starting buffer receive
ob_get_clean() cleans current buffer and returns its value.

More info on http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

ob * output buffering

Comment: because it hasn't been explicitly said, this is called "output buffering", hence the `ob`.

Comment: Can I do this as I call the function like ob_start(); j_uf_SomeFunction('blah'); $html = ob_end_clean();

Comment: I hav just updated code, one minor mistake, and yes you can do it your way

Comment: Switching in and out of PHP within a function or method is bad form :-) If you want the html "template" self contained within the function then call your php functions first and assign them to a token array, then use `strtr` to replace the tokens in the html string (or use `sprintf` with mutliple position based variables), otherwise just use an include after you start the buffer to include an external php file.

Comment: Its better this way, if you are calling method from two places or more, you don't have to write ob_start... always but if you do it your way than you will ahve to always write ob methods

Comment: You could use [ob_get_clean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) instead of the calls to `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_end_clean()`

Comment: @prodigitalson The function does a lot more than I'm showing. It adds user options to the image, collects the location of the image in the apporpraite server among other things...

Comment: @Justin you can always use echo j_uf_SomeFunction($some_var) if you need to send output to buffer immediately

Comment: I don't I have a template system to parse this functions value into... its not your standard function call.

Comment: Ps. It was I don't have a simple thing going on... here

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like output buffers are one possible solution to your problem.

You use an output buffer like so:

```
ob_start();
j_uf_SomeFunction($someVar);
$buffer = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

The $buffer variable now contains anything printed out by the function.

It's important to always close output buffers with ob_end_clean or ob_end_flush. You can read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php

Regards,
  Chris

Comment: Thank you, so I should use ob_end_flush at the end of clean?

Comment: It's not necessary and could cause a warning. ob_end_clean clears the output buffer you start with ob_start, whereas ob_end_flush prints what's in the output buffer before emptying it. You either use one or the other :-)

Answer (score 1):

> I don't I have a template system to parse this functions value into... its not your standard function call.

sure you do... its jsut contained within the function :-)

using translation:

```
function j_uf_SomeFunction($some_var) {
    $html = "<div class="db_photo"><img alt="%some_function_result%" src="%some_var%" /></div>";
    $tokens = array(
      '%some_var%' => $some_var,
      '%some_function_call_result%' => some_function_call()
    );

    return strtr($html, $tokens); // or echo
}
```

using string manipulation:

```
function j_uf_SomeFunction($some_var) {
    $html = '<div class="db_photo"><img alt="%s" src="%s" /></div>';

    return sprintf($html, some_function_call(), $some_var); //or echo
}
```

if `some_function_call` actually outputs html directly with its own echo then jsut use a buffer:

```
   function j_uf_SomeFunction($some_var) {
    ob_start();
    some_function_call();
    $somefunc = ob_get_clean();

    $html = '<div class="db_photo"><img alt="%s" src="%s" /></div>';
    return sprintf($html, $somefunc, $some_var); //or echo
}
```

Comment: Great, now you'd like me to rewrite my entire web service... terrible people. Lol.

Comment: I find it much easier to spit out context in html, for wire framing and to keep in standards. This is also why I like php as apposed to any other solution that wants me to manipulate the whole site from strings... I'm doing advanced data manipulation... If its still advisable, I suppose its better to stick with standards than not.

Comment: P.S. The above function was just an example... The real function connects to a database and prints out the image. The function I'm calling this function from takes a string like "<div id="title">{{title}}</div><div id="post">{{image:{{urf}}}} {{post data}}</div>" and parses the {{}} commands for building a line item (stream post). This paritucluar one looks for {{image:x}} (using a regexpr) and calls the image grabber. The function that I based my example off of. Still Following?